# Do i have to pay to google if i am using their Map- API in my app?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am building an iphone/iPad app where i need to use google maps API, so do i have to pay google for using it. I know we can use it for free but is there any legal attachments with this.

I know this is not a programming question but i just can't think of any other place to ask this question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).  This is very likely the wrong place to ask that though.

Comment: Specifically, take a look at Section 9 of the Google Maps API – the whole document is an extended answer to your question, but as of today Google's terms explicitly allow you to use the Maps API in "a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store" without making payment to Google.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually i know this but some person just cut me in a meeting so just wanted to make sure. And i am really sorry for putting this question here but as i said i couldn't think of any other place to post this.